# In Windows 7, my user profile cannot be loaded, how do I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, safe-mode

After uninstalling an HP Vector mouse driver, then rebooting, when Windows tries to auto log me in, I get an error message saying the following.

> The User Profile Service failed the Login. User Profile cannot be loaded.

Due to the fact that it is the only account on this PC, I cannot even go into another account.

I rebooted the machine several times, before going into Safe Mode with Networking. For some reason, I cannot create a new account whilst in safe mode (I think it is to do with [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control), nothing with UAC is clickable).

Thus, I am stuck. I cannot get into my account, nor can I create a new one to copy files over to.

How do I fix this problem?

EDIT: System Restore was, for some reason turned off. Thus, I cannot restore to a working point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your user profile is not corrupted, but that Windows is having trouble loading it (think a bad hard drive). You can boot into the Windows 7 Recovery Console from your Windows 7 DVD. Open the command prompt and start a chkdsk.

If your profile is actual corrupted, you can try a system restore. This will restore your profile back to an earlier date. Again, use the Windows 7 DVD to do this.

You may also be able to rename the user profile using the command prompt (eg

`cd \Users`

`ren UserAccount UserAccount.old`

And then try to log in, Windows might complain of a different problem but it should recreate a profile for you.

EDIT: Are you sure you are the only user? Unless you are **the** local administrator, there should also be an "Administrator" account.

Comment: I forgot to mention that System Restore, for some reason was turned off. So no previous restore points have been created. 

I will try chkdsk, then try renaming and let you know how i go. Thanks

Comment: also, there is no administrator account that I am aware of. There is no administrator folder in /Users, and I cannot view a list of users in Control Panel > User Accounts because safe mode does not allow it. Can you think of anything else that could solve this issue?

Comment: As a last ditch effort, I would try booting into the recovery mode from the DVD and try to create a new user using "net user <username> <password>" and then "net localgroup Administrators <username> /add". You may want to also try this from "Safe Mode With Console". Otherwise get yourself and external hard drive and xcopy/robocopy C:\Users\YourProfile to the external drive plus whatever other data you have. You may also use a Linux LiveCD to accomplish this. Otherwise... best of luck and I'm sorry that I wasn't able to help further.

Comment: You may also want to try these tricks to see if you can elevate yourself to administrator: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vista/vista_administrative_privileges.htm

Comment: Any idea why this happens? I've had this same problem happen twice on the same profile

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fix if you have only one account:

1. Boot into Safe Mode, with the option to use Command Prompt
2. Disable the User Control Account in the registry; use `regedit` to navigate to the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
   ```
3. Change the value of `EnableLUA` to 0.
4. Reboot and login normally.

Your profile still might not load, but at least you get a temporary one - now you can make a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around I found this [guide and forum](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/130095-user-profile-service-failed-logon-user-profile-cannot-loaded.html) detailing the problem and various solutions. I suggest having a read: there are 81 pages of additional posts after the guide so a working solution for you should be in there somewhere.